# Using lerna with a forked package

Tags: typescript, monorepo, lerna

I have a monorepo managed by lerna and I'm trying to add a forked package to it.
I forked the package to fix a bug, but while the pull request is still open I want to be able to keep working.

Note that the fork is used by my normal public dependencies, and I need them to use the fork too, without forking them also.

Whats the correct way of doing that?

Currently I tried adding it to the mono repo with the same name, but with a different version. This seems to work for the other packages in the monorepo, but my dependencies don't seem to find it, which makes sense.

Is there a way to link the forked package into the root node_modules? If so, I think the other packages will find it.

Thanks

Comment: you should use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@milahu/patch-package). For an example, I found this [commit](https://github.com/wundergraph/wundergraph/commit/a8f18ba34c257a48287b3b05326db07000d8cc84) on public repo that uses pnpm (I don't own neither use that repo), the concept is the same for other package manager.